# WCF Data Services saving data/entity issue

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to save data back to the database via WCF but I keep getting:

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'ResellerPlatform.dbo.Contacts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.` (System.Data.UpdateException)

The same happens via a WebGet on the service side itself:

```
[WebGet]
public void AddContact()
{
    var Contact = new Models.ResellerPlatform.Contact
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Foo"
    };

    base.CurrentDataSource.AddToContacts(Contact);
    base.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();
}
```

The Contact model is a basic entity with an Id (Guid) and a Name (string), no relationships or anything. Here's my access rules:

```
Config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
Config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
```

I can't understand why it keeps throwing the exception as Id **isn't** null. Ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Are you using sql server? It looks like the Id column is not filled. You might use sql profiler to see what is sent to the sql server.

Comment: How is Id mapped? Btw. GET operation should never be used for anything which modifies data in your application.

Comment: @rudolf_franek, Ladislav Mrnka Yes, I know. I'm just using it to debug as it's easier :-) Good idea on the SQL profiler but I suspect it will be NULL, any idea why WCF would do that?

Comment: I expect you are using your browser for GET requests - I mostly use www.fiddler2.com - it allows to use all http methods and reading headers easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed setting the **StoreGeneratedPattern** to none resolved the issue when using a Guid for the primary key - I thought EF could handle Guid's as primary keys?

Comment: EF 4 can handle GUIDs with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity` while EF 1 can't. But you have to generate the id value on the database side! You have told that you don't do this, so there is your error. EF expects the value to be set by the database. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sound to me like EF is expecting the database to generate the value of your Id key column.

Generally you have to options:

1. Generate the id value on the client side (c# code) as you did and set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property to `none`.
2. Generate the id value on the database side and set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property to `Identity`.

The second option is not supported with EF Version 1. You have to open and modify the edmx file in a xml editor to get this to work (see this [blog entry](http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/) for details).

What you did is a mix of both options: You set the value in your client code but tell EF with `StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity` that the database will generate the value.

Comment: The Id column is just a uniqueidentifier, no default values or anything. http://imgur.com/F09bw

Comment: Have you checked the mapping?

Comment: What is the value of the StoreGeneratedPattern property of the Id Property?

Comment: The default value (Identity).